# PHP preg_match URL Segment Not Working

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string:

```
https://domain.tld/123456/api/v1/projects/45242457-foo-bar.json
```

And I'm trying to match '45242457-foo-bar' using:

```
preg_match('~"/projects/(.*).json"~', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

This keeps returning zero matches. Why?

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around the URL?

Comment: What are the surrounding `"` for?

Comment: Consider using `parse_url()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get info about urls. It is a much easier and better solution than a regex.

Comment: Great questions. I saw another SO post where it said preg_match required delimiters around the pattern. I'll try to find it ...

Comment: @doremi You have delimiters around your pattern. The tildes (`~`) are your delimiters in this case

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your period (and a greedy *):

```
~"/projects/(.*?)\.json"~
```

Comment: He does, but that's not the cause of the problem, the cause is a greedy `*`

Comment: Overlooked that. Regex modified accordingly.

Comment: @DaveRandom Actually not a problem here. Works just fine leaving the asterisk as-is. The problem is actually the double quotes. Just fixing that makes this work. Although I agree the `.` should be escaped to stick with what the OP is trying to do

Comment: Would be more helpful to put the entire solution (this works) preg_match('~/projects/(.*?)\.json~', $project->url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);